# Finding a value in a php array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, match

I've been banging my head hard over this problem for the last 2-3 days trying to see the problem from as many different angles as possible but to no avail. I'm turning to the SO community for extra perspectives. Below is the code I have which prints all 9 product plans. I'm wanting to find and print the plan with pricing equals or closest to a given user input. How can I do this?

```
//arrays of productnames
$productnames=array(1=>"Beginner","Advanced","Expert");

//arrays of productlevels
$productlevels=array(1=>"Bronze","Silver","Gold");

//Get The Length of Product Name Array
$planname_array_length=count($productnames);

//Get The Length of Product Level Array
$planlevel_array_length=count($productlevels);

for ($prn=1; $prn <= $planname_array_length; $prn++) {//loop to create plan name indicators 
    for ($prl=1; $prl <= $planlevel_array_length; $prl++) {//loop to create plan level indicators 

        $getpoductsql = " SELECT name, level,productNameId,productLevelId,finalProductPrice
                        FROM ( 
                        SELECT wspn.productName AS name, wspl.productLevel AS level, wsp.productNameId AS productNameId, wsp.productPlanLevel AS productLevelId, 
                        ROUND(SUM(`Price`) * 1.12) AS finalProductPrice,
                        FROM `products` ws 
                        left join product_plan wsp on wsp.productId = ws.wsid 
                        left join product_plan_level wspl on wsp.productPlanLevel = wspl.wsplid 
                        left join product_plan_name wspn on wspn.wspnid = wsp.productNameId 
                        WHERE wspn.productName = '$planname_array_length[$pn]' AND wspl.productLevel = '$planlevel_array_length[$pl]'
                        )
                        AS x ORDER BY ABS(finalProductPrice - $compareprice)"
            $resultproducts = $conn->query($getpoductsql);
        $prodArray = mysqli_fetch_array($resultproducts);

        //print array of each plan
        $resultArr = array('planNameID' => $prodArray['planNameId'], 
                           'planName' => $prodArray['name'], 
                           'planLevelID' => $prodArray['planLevelId'],
                           'planLevelName' => $prodArray['level'],
                           'planPrice' => $prodArray['finalProductPrice'];

                           //print arrays of products
                           echo json_encode($resultArr);

    }
}
```

This will output 9 plans as follow :

```
{"planNameID":"1","productName":"Beginner","productLevelID":"1","productLevelName":"Bronze","productPrice":"15"}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @AmrBerag: How can I find the plan with pricing equal or closest to user input? If I do it inside the forloops it prints all 9 plans regardless of what I do. I need to do it outside the loop for some reason but I don't see how I would do that.

Comment: I assum your sql is working fine, is it?

Comment: @AmrBerag: Yes the whole code is working and printing fine.

Comment: Take the first one, it should be the one, when prl = 1

Comment: It looks like you're using the solution I posted yesterday in the duplicate question, you just forgot to put `LIMIT 1` in the query.

Comment: @Barmar I think he wants somthing a little bit different

Comment: I have a feeling Frank and Gary are the same poster. Some of the variables here are the same as in the previous question.

Comment: @Barmar: No this is not what I want. I have seen your answer you left on this other dude Gary's post. It was inspired from his answer but I'm wanting something different than his.

Comment: maybe they are Colleagues. I think he want a 3*3 html table  with lowest price for each plan intersection with gold, selver and bronze

Comment: Are you looking for the closest one among all the results of the `for` loop?

Comment: If so, why don't you get rid of the loop and let the query search all the plans, rather than one plan at a time?

Comment: @Barmar: That is correct. I'm looking for the closest one among all the results of the for loop.

Comment: @Barmar: How do you mean?

Comment: @Frank he ment if you have kept the limit you will get 9 results

Comment: @AmrBerag: I tried Gary's code. I copied it and even ran it. That's not what I need. LIMIT 1 does not do anything. All the 9 results print on the page and that's not what I'm wanting to do in my program. I'm wanting to sort of iterate  over the 9 results and put in the json array the product with pricing equal or closest to user input $compareprice.

Comment: @Frank check my answer it should give you a json with lowest instance of each plan . if it doesn't work stick to Balmar and try to explain what you want to him, he is a good programmer than I'm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than performing a separate query for each product name and product level, do them all in one query, and let MySQL find the one with the closest price.

```
   $getpoductsql = " SELECT name, level,productNameId,productLevelId,finalProductPrice
                    FROM ( 
                    SELECT wspn.productName AS name, wspl.productLevel AS level, wsp.productNameId AS productNameId, wsp.productPlanLevel AS productLevelId, 
                    ROUND(SUM(`Price`) * 1.12) AS finalProductPrice,
                    FROM `products` ws 
                    left join product_plan wsp on wsp.productId = ws.wsid 
                    left join product_plan_level wspl on wsp.productPlanLevel = wspl.wsplid 
                    left join product_plan_name wspn on wspn.wspnid = wsp.productNameId 
                    WHERE wspn.productName IN ('Beginner', 'Advanced', 'Expert') AND wspl.productLevel IN ('Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold')
                    GROUP BY productNameId, productLevelId
                    )
                    AS x ORDER BY ABS(finalProductPrice - $compareprice)"
```

Comment: Dude you're a genius. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

*forgive my formatting, I'm on mobile*

Like Amr Berag said above, your result should be the first row returned from your query.

If you have a table like this:

```
ID    value
----   ------
A       7
B       12
C       23
...
```

You can then `SELECT` from this table to find the closest to some value, like so:

*(Assume your desired value is $VALUE)*

```
SELECT id, value, ABS(value - $VALUE) AS diff
FROM your_table
ORDER BY diff ASC
```

This will return something like this (say $VALUE is 10):

```
id  value  diff
--  ------  ----
B    12   2
A    7     3
C    23   13
...
```

You can just pick the first row.

You may also be able to add a WHERE clause to only select the row with the least difference using the `MIN` function:

```
SELECT id, value, ABS(value - $VALUE) AS diff
FROM your_table
WHERE diff = MIN(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it will produce invalid json, do it like this:

```
  $result=array(); 
    for ($prn=1; $prn <= $planname_array_length; $prn++) {   
      for ($prl=1; $prl <= $planlevel_array_length; $prl++) {   
            .     .     .     // the other code   
     //print array of each plan          
   $resultArr = array('planNameID' => $prodArray['planNameId'],    
                             'planName' => $prodArray['name'],                                 'planLevelID' => $prodArray['planLevelId'],                 
               'planLevelName' => $prodArray['level'],   
        'planPrice' => $prodArray['finalProductPrice']; 
                                    //print arrays of products     
                            $resul[]=$resultArr;        
                                      }//loop1   
  }//loop2   

      echo json_encode($result);
```

you should also add the limit 1 and do the rest in JS in the front end